# The optimal way to lock and write to a file in Scala on Linux

Tags: java, linux, scala, file, filesystems

I'm having a hard time finding the correct way to do any advanced file-system operations on Linux using Scala.

The one which I really can't figure out if best described by the following pseudo-code:

```
with fd = open(path, append | create):
    with flock(fd, exclusive_lock):
        fd.write(string)
```

Basically open a file in append mode (create it if it's non existent), get an exclusive lock to it and write to it (with the implicit unlock and close afterwards).

Is there an easy, clean and efficient way of doing this if I know my program will be ran on linux only ? (preferably without glancing offer the exceptions that should be handled).

Edit:

The answer I got is, as far as I've seen and tested is correct. However it's quite verbose, so I'm marking it as ok but I'm leaving this snippet of code here, which is the one I ended up using (Not sure if it's correct, but as far as I see it does everything that I need):

```
  val fc  = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(file_path), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
  try {
    fc.lock()
    fc.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
  } finally { fc.close() }
```

Comment: *Why* do you need to lock the file? What *problem* is locking the file supposed to solve? You have no guarantee that any underlying file system supports locking.

Comment: "Why do you need to lock the file?" Generally speaking locking is needed to ensure a resource that is accessed by multiple threads out of which at least one is a writer can be written to and read from "safely", that is, with all operations being order after on another. So assuming I have a process A writing to a file "X" whilst process B reads from the same file "X" I would need a lock on the file to safely use it.

Comment: "You have no guarantee that any underlying file system supports locking", As far as I knew most (read: all) modern file systems have a somewhat compatible file locking interface, outside of network file systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FileChannel.lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock--) and [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) to get what you wanted:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths, StandardOpenOption}

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object ExclusiveFsWrite {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val path = Paths.get("/tmp/file")
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("Some text data here".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

    val fc = getExclusiveFileChannel(path)
    try {
      fc.write(buffer)
    }
    finally {
      // channel close will also release a lock
      fc.close()
    }

    ()
  }

  private def getExclusiveFileChannel(path: Path): FileChannel = {
    // Append if exist or create new file (if does not exist)
    val fc = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
      StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
    if (fc.size > 0) {
      // set position to the end
      fc.position(fc.size - 1)
    }
    // get an exclusive lock
    Try(fc.lock()) match {
      case Success(lock) =>
        println("Is shared lock: " + lock.isShared)
        fc
      case Failure(ex) =>
        Try(fc.close())
        throw ex
    }
  }
}
```